# @Inject ResourceDescriptionsProvider rdp; is null

Tags: eclipse-plugin, indexing, dsl, xtext

I am trying to instantiate xtext index.
I found that I should inject this object, but from what I tried it is always null;

I have put following code in different classes:

```
@Inject
private ResourceDescriptionsProvider resourceDescriptionsProvider;

public List<IResourceDescription> getResourceDescriptionsFor(IProject project)
{               
    IResourceDescriptions xtextIndex = resourceDescriptionsProvider.createResourceDescriptions();           
    return descriptions;
}
```

But, resourceDescriptionsProvider is always null, WHY?
The plugin.xml has

```
 <extension
         point="org.eclipse.xtext.builder.participant">
      <participant
            class="com.dsl.mydsl.ui.MydslExecutableExtensionFactory:com.dsl.mydsl.ui.builder.Builder">
      </participant>
   </extension>
```

Does anyone knows what is wrong or missing.
Thanks

Comment: In which class are you trying to inject ResourceDescriptionsProvider and what is supposed to trigger this action?

Comment: I tried in different dsl classes: 1. In class that extends ResourceDescriptionsProvider; 2. The class that extends org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.impl.AbstractDeclarativeScopeProvider; 3. In MyDslStandaloneSetup that extends MyDslStandaloneSetupGenerated implements org.eclipse.xtext.ISetup;

Comment: And I am trying to instantiate xtext indexer in order to be able to implement different functionalities for my dsl based, like new Tab in eclipse search, navigation, etc.